# Derived Class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that it can be a stupid but I even don't know how to name this question. I'm non native English. I learn C++ from a book and there is a program which shows name and pay rate of employee (base class) and `Manager` (derived class) with added `bool` variable `salaried`. Here is the source code:

```
//base class
class Employee {
private:
    string name;
    double pay;
public:
    Employee() {
        name = "";
        pay = 0;
    }

    Employee(string empName, double payRate) {
        name = empName;
        pay = payRate;
    }

    string getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(string empName) {
        name = empName;
    }

    double getPay() const {
        return pay;
    }

    void setPay(double payRate) {
        pay = payRate;
    }

    string toString() {
        stringstream stm;
        stm << name << ": " << pay;
        return stm.str();

    }
};

//derived class
class Manager : public Employee {
private:
    bool salaried;
public:
    Manager(string name, double payRate, bool isSalaried)
        :Employee(name, payRate)
    {
        salaried = isSalaried;
    }
    bool getSalaried() {
        return salaried;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employee emp1("Mary Smith", 15.00);
    cout << "Employee name: " << emp1.getName() << endl;
    cout << "Employee pay rate: " << emp1.getPay() << endl;
    Manager emp2("Bob Brown", 1500, true);
    cout << "Employee name: " << emp2.getName() << endl;
    cout << "Employee pay rate: " << emp2.getPay() << endl;
    cout << "Is Salaried: " << emp2.getSalaried() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain me why this part

```
:Employee(name, payRate)
```

must be added to code to work properly?

Comment: This just calls `Employee`'s constructor

Comment: It is a way to call Employee's parameterised constructor. The base class Default constructor is by default called but one has to call parameterized constructor explicitliy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
:Employee(name, payRate)
```

you mention is used to call the constructor

```
Employee(string empName, double payRate)
```

of the base class `Employee` before executing the body of the constructor

```
Manager(string name, double payRate, bool isSalaried)
```

of the derived class `Manager`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The combination of username and profile picture took me several steps to make up!

Comment: Where there's a Wyllis there's a way.

Answer (score 1):

It calls the base class's (Employee) constructor and passes the `name` and `payRate` to it because they are members of Employee.

Answer (score 0):

```
:Employee(name, payRate)
```

is the initialisation of the base class that class `Manager` inherits.

Answer (score 0):

In fact without this line the code should compile fine(because you have a default constructor for `Employee`), but the fields inherited from `Employee` will not get properly initialized in `emp2`. What this portion of the code does is to call the constructor of `Employee` to initialize the fields inherited from that class.

Answer (score 0):

What come after the colon on the constructor called [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) and in your case it just initiate the base class with the suitable constructor

Answer (score 0):

The code can work properly even without the constructor(i.e..you can use the default constructor to accept the variables and implement two methods for filling the `name` and `pay`.)

```
class Employee {
private:
    string name;
    string temp_name;
    double temp_pay;
    double pay;
public:
    Employee() {
        name = temp_name;
        pay = temp_pay;
    }

    void getTempname(string tem){temp_name = tem;}
    void getTemppay(double py){ temp_pay = pay;}
};
```